# Nested IF / ELSE Statements in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

Can I place IF statements inside of other IF statements?

For Example

```
if %size% GTR 0 (
     if exist C:\Job\Resume.txt (
        echo File Exist
     ) else (
        echo No File Exist
     )
echo File Size Greater Than Zero
) else (
echo File Not Greater Than Zero
)
```

Can IF/Else Statements be placed inside other IF/Else Statements in Batch Programs, with just using indentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes! You just missed a left paren at end of this line: `if exist C:\Job\Resume.txt`

Comment: Does that look correct? So I can continue to nest IF / Else statements just like the above format?

Comment: Yes... Just remember that the expansion of empty variables can lead to errors. For example, if `%size%` var have no value it causes a syntax error: `if  GTR 0 (`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can nest `IF` statements. Did you not test your script to find out? =)

Indentation does not matter, as long as `else` is on the same line as `)` and `(`.

Keep in mind that the %variables% in the entire IF statement will be resolved at once, unless you use delayed expansion.

Edit: I just noticed you're missing a `(` on your second `IF`.

```
     if exist C:\Job\Resume.txt (
```

Comment: It wouldn't run correctly for me, so I wasn't sure if I was even able to do it! I must be entering in something wrong on my PC. Thanks for the quick answer!